# QPrintDialog: Disable Print Button

Tags: c++, qt, qprinter

As per the title, I want to disable/remove Print Button from the QPrintDialog.

Is there anyway to achieve this ??

I need to show only printer setting page, where user can define printer settings and Apply the changes.

Can anyone suggest me the way to disable Print Button ??

Or is there any way to create Printer Settings Page with customize button ??

Comment: Interesting question, +1, but I think you will need to implement it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
QPrintDialog printDialog;

QList<QPushButton *> allButtons = printDialog.findChildren<QPushButton *>();

for (int i = 0; i < allButtons.size(); i++) {
   if (allButtons.at(i)->text().contains("Print")) {
      allButtons.at(i)->setDisabled(true);
      break;
   }
}

printDialog.exec();
```

A bit of a hack, but should work.

Comment: This code does not work